# Why is Picasa ruining my raw files

Tags: picasa

I've used picasa for years with my Canon and I don't remember having any problems with my CR2 files. I'm now using a Sony A7 and Picasa shows all my .ARW photos with this grey haze as if I put a VSCO filter on all of them. They appear just fine in Lightroom and Photoshop. I only ever use Picasa for mass sorting/deleting photos and for backing them up to my google account so if I can't fix this what other software would be good for that purpose?

Lightroom:

[image: Lightroom]

Picasa:

[image: Picasa]

Comment: It looks like there are plugins available for LR to sync with google drive, would that be an option?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the answers from [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41327/why-do-raw-images-look-worse-than-jpegs-in-editing-programs/41336#41336) should help.  In short it'll probably be Picasa's default RAW processing being different to LR's (and the camera's).

Comment: I think it's just a RAW compatibility problem. I used Phase One software, then updated the firmware of my camera and the .NEF files I got wouldn't load anymore.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and assume that "Because Picasa is awful but it doesn't matter because google will kill it off in about 18 months." would not be the constructive answer the community needs...

Comment: My guess is that this is a conversion without the camera profile - a RAWTherape conversion will look similar without a camera profile. A camera profile covers things like weighing the individual RGB channels, response of the sensor to individual colours etc.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same issue with Picasa with my CR2 [canon raw] files from my T4i when it still worked fine for the CR2 files from my T2i and after looking into it, it has to do with the system files for reading the raw files. Picasa relies on the OS to give it the way to read the file where lightroom keeps it own method of reading raw files. Canon offers a way for one to download a Raw File Codec and you have to be the one to keep this codec up to date from the manufacturer. I am not familiar with wife's Sony camera's raw format in Picasa as I have moved to fully using Lightroom at home and only use Picasa if I'm at work and i need a picture off the Canon camera.

I have yet to test the CR2 files from the 7D mk ii yet.

[Canon Raw Codec](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/digital_cameras/software_applications/canon_raw_codec_software)

[Sony Raw Driver](http://esupport.sony.com/swu/4025/US/) (sony calls it's it a driver canon does not)

Comment: My Mistake, its not a driver, its a codec, just wanted to correct my self

Comment: You should edit the post itself to correct the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've used a special function of Picasa. Hide/Unhide pictures.

Unhide pictures

- Click the View menu.
- Select Hidden Pictures. Your hidden pictures will now appear, but they will be *translucent*.
- Select the photos that you'd like to unhide.
- Click the View menu.
- Select Unhide.

Answer (score 0):

Different programs handle raw files differently.  Picasa will generate its own preview/thumbnail for pictures after it reads the raw file.  Initially it will use the embedded jpeg preview.  Lightroom also uses the embedded preview, and will later generate its own processed preview.