# How to use JPG embedded in RAW for color calibration in darktable

Tags: raw, color, color-management, jpeg, darktable

My camera (Canon EOS R5) does a great job with colors for the embedded JPG, but I am unable to achieve similar colors (mainly skin tones) when processing the RAW version of the image in darktable.

I was wondering that it must be algorithmically possible to use the embedded JPG to adjust the color profile automatically. Is there a function for this in darktable? I was not able to find it.

Comment: Set white balance to "as per shot"

Comment: I do that, but that does not cut it

Comment: To be able to perfectly reproduce Canon's algorithms… use Canon's software. All 3rd parties must guess, and rarely get it right. See https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/96952/why-does-the-histogram-of-an-image-depends-on-the-software-that-opened-it

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is no such functionality in darktable.

Answer (score 0):

When shooting raw, white balance should be set to Auto, with the understanding that anything can be adjusted in converting Raw files to pixels.

If your raw file conversion tool is inadequate, try another tool—Adobe Photoshop with Camera Raw.  Then simply open the image you want to match in Photoshop and open the Raw file version in Camera Raw.  Adjust the raw file to match the .jpeg file visually and save the settings.  That will get you close for the same type of image.